# Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Tags: javascript

Code run perfectly for around a day then suddenly started giving this error

> Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
>
> at getBankAccountAddr (chrome-extension://alkobbcomnpmkogigmgchodloihahjnd/core/libraries/helpers/functions/getBankAccountAddr.js:10:110)
>
> at Object.appendControlPanel (chrome-extension://alkobbcomnpmkogigmgchodloihahjnd/core/views.js:10:24)
>
> at controlPanel (chrome-extension://alkobbcomnpmkogigmgchodloihahjnd/core/controllers/controlPanel.js:13:11)
>
> at chrome-extension://alkobbcomnpmkogigmgchodloihahjnd/core/controllers/bootstrap.js:20:9
>
> at runSequence (chrome-extension://alkobbcomnpmkogigmgchodloihahjnd/core/libraries/helpers/classes/Storage.js:18:21)

Here is the code it is referring to:

- getbankAccountAddr.js

```
var bankip = accountWidgets[i].innerHTML.match(/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/m)[0]
```

- views.js

```
var bankInfo = getBankAccountAddr()
```

- controlPanel.js

```
views.appendControlPanel()
```

- bootstrap.js

```
controlPanel()
```

- storage.js

```
callback(getResponse.message)
```

If you want any more code for any of the errors just ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there are no machches,

**Which Means,**
Your code,

```js
accountWidgets[i].innerHTML.match(/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/m)
```

Will try to find any matches for given `regex`, If there are no matches, It will return **NULL**. So you **can't** read the **0 index** of **NULL**

So you need to add validation something like,

```js
var matches = accountWidgets[i].innerHTML.match(/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/m);

if ( matches === null ) {
  // you implementation if there are no matches
} else {
  bankip = matches[0];
}
```